# how to insert checked items from checkedlistbox plus range of times into table?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

The codes below only loop the first checked item in checkedlistbox, i want it to be able to loop every checked items plus ranges of start date and end date and after that insert into table.  result in table will be:

```
user  |  01.01.14
user  |  01.02.14
user  |  01.03.14
user  |  01.04.14
```

---

```
user2  |  02.01.14
user2  |  02.02.14
user2  |  02.03.14
user2  |  02.04.14
```

But with the code below only produce result of the first checked item, although i did check multiple items.

The preferred outcome was incorrect, Who can help or guide me on this??

```
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & aaa & "';Persist Security Info=False;")
    Dim stard As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim endd As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value

    'Dim itemchecked As Object
    'For Each itemchecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
    Dim count = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count
    'CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To (count - 1)
        Dim checked = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(0)
        Do While stard <= endd
            Dim insertinto As String = "INSERT INTO try ([SN],[Dateplease]) VALUES (@SN, @Dateplease)"
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insertinto, connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SN", checked)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dateplease", stard)
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connection.Open()
            End If
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            stard = stard.AddDays(1)
        Loop
        'Next
    Next
    connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim checked = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(i)
```

And you need to reset your start date value back to its original value
Add this

```
Dim originalstard As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim stard As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim endd As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
```

Then after the `Loop` keyword add

```
Loop
stard = originalstard
```

Comment: thx for the help, i put it to (i) it still only loop first checked item!!

Comment: whats the value on the count variable?